# $R^{(\mathbb{N})} \cong R^{(\mathbb{N})} \oplus R^{(\mathbb{N})} $?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring. Consider the $R-$module $R^{(\mathbb{N})}$ of infinite sequences with components in $R$ and with at most finitely many nonzero components.
I wish to show that there is an $R-$module isomorphism between $R^{(\mathbb{N})}$ and $R^{(\mathbb{N})} \oplus R^{(\mathbb{N})}  $.

I can think of homomorphisms that are injective and some that are surjective. However, I cannot think of a bijective homomorphism. Is it possible to use ideas from exact sequences?

If not, any suggestions for an isomorphism would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Please include some context and your own thoughts in the question. What have your tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You only have to construct a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N \sqcup \Bbb N$ (union of two copies of $\Bbb N$). I suppose you know how to do this.

It then gives a bijection between the base elements, hence an $R$-module isomorphism.

Comment: Is there an explicit function for a bijection between these two sets? I know at least $\mathbb{N} \sqcup \mathbb{N} $ is countable, and thus there is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N} \sqcup \mathbb{N}$. I just don't know how to define one.

Comment: Send $x \in \Bbb N$ to $x / 2$ in the first copy if $x$ is even, and to $(x - 1) / 2$ in the second copy if $x$ is odd.

Comment: If we do this, then what in $\mathbb{N}$ maps to say $(1,1)$?

Comment: $\Bbb N\sqcup \Bbb N$ is not the cartesian product $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$. It's rather $\Bbb N \times \{0, 1\}$, if you like.